# Prevent the row scroll on edit click

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I built a data grid using
[Kendo Angular Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) in which i have given size to each columns and also has command button "Edit, Update, Cancel" as very last columns.
Due to size of columns, grid gets horizontal scroll bars.
Editing is allowed only in last two field columns.
When ever i click on "Edit" button the row scrolls to very left and my editable columns + command buttons ("update"&"cancel") hided this is something weird or not liking to user. Again user has to scroll to right and do the update/cancel operation.
Does any one has solution to this issue.

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="view" [height]="700" [pageSize]="25" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [selectable]="true"
                (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)" (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)" 
                (save)="saveHandler($event)">
                <!-- <kendo-grid-messages 
            noRecords="{{ this.noRecordMsg }}">
        </kendo-grid-messages> -->
                <kendo-grid-column title="View" width="60">
                    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">

                        <button kendoButton [icon]="'hyperlink-open'" [look]="'outline'" [routerLink]="['/detail', dataItem.ID]"></button>


                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="FILE_NAME" title="File Name" width="140"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="FILE_DATE" title="File Date" width="90">
                    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                        {{ dataItem.FILE_DATE | date:"shortDate" }}
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="AMT" title="AMT" width="80"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="NAME" title="Name" width="90"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="ID" title="ID" width="80"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="PI" title="PI" width="110">
                    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="PIListItems" [value]="dataItem.PI" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.PI" name="PI"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="STATUS" title="Status" width="100">
                    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="statusListItems" [value]="dataItem.STATUS" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.STATUS" name="STATUS"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-command-column title="command" width="180">
                    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew" let-dataItem="dataItem">
                        <button kendoGridEditCommand class="k-primary">Edit</button>
                        <button kendoGridSaveCommand [disabled]="myForm.invalid">{{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}</button>
                        <button kendoGridCancelCommand>{{ isNew ? 'Discard changes' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-command-column>
                <ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
                    <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
                    <kendo-pager-numeric-buttons [buttonCount]="5"></kendo-pager-numeric-buttons>
                    <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
                    <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
                    <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="[25, 50, 100, 200]"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how exactly your edit handler looks like but Grid have (edit) emitter according to the documentation.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/

I believe if you add this in template:

```
<kendo-grid (edit)="onGridEdit($event)">...</kendo-grid>
```

And then in the component try add the following:

```
onGridEdit($event: any): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

It will help.

Comment: I am getting error  **ERROR TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function
ERROR TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function** 

May be i am missing some import. Please help

Comment: Please check if you pass it with $ from the template

Comment: Yes i am passing it as $ 
`<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="view" [height]="700" [pageSize]="25" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [selectable]="true"
                    (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)" (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)" 
                    (save)="saveHandler($event)">`

Comment: Can you show the client-side code that you use to edit cell / row?

Comment: `protected editHandler(event: any) {
      this.closeEditor(event.sender);
      this.editedRowIndex = event.rowIndex;
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
      this.editedStatus = Object.assign({}, event.dataItem);
      event.sender.editRow(event.rowIndex);
    }`

Comment: Ok, I see. We need to find different solution probably. Are you editing in-cell or whole row?